# Azure firewall UDR NAT

Tags: azure

I have jump host subnet behind the firewall and I use NAT rule to translate my jump host Windows virtual machine private IP.

Problem is when I try to remote my jump host machine using NAT rule I will get the error message. But, I check my nat and network rule logs in the firewall. I has Dnat to my jump host machine and the status is allowed.

my jump host route table setting:

1. address prefix:**0.0.0.0/0** next-hop:**172.168.2.4(firewall private IP)**
2. address prefix:**172.168.1.0/24(jump host subnet)** next-hop:**172.168.2.4(firewall private IP)**

my firewall rule setting:

1. Nat rule
   srcIp:*** or my public ip** DesIp:**my firewall public IP** DesPort:**3389** TranslateIP:**172.168.1.x(my jump host machine)** TranslatePort:**3389**
2. Network Rule
   srcIP:***** DesIP:**172.168.1.x(my jump host machine)** DesPort:**3389**

**Update message:**

I use remote desktop in windows and if I remove the route table routes. I can use the NAT rule entry jump host machine.

**Remove this rule:**

(2. address prefix:**172.168.1.0/24(jump host subnet)** next-hop:**172.168.2.4(firewall private IP)**)

I don't have a reputation post image. But error like this one:

https://cdn.myquickcloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/22101755/rdc_error_01-e1493822388204.png

Comment: 1) What is the error message? 2) What is the Protocol? 3) Did you create the Network Rule? If yes, this is not necessary. Remove it to test. 4) Is port 3389 open in the Windows host?

Comment: 1)my error is a connective error like remote access not enabled, the machine is turned and the machine is not available on the network. 2)TCP/UDP 3) I have the network security rule and i allow anyany for RDP connect.4.yes, and I stop and disable windows firewall test.

Comment: I need the exact error message. Also, what command are you using that generates the error? Edit your question with more details.